# Angular 7 LOCALE_ID Injection using plain old objects

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, localization

Im working with locale injection and i am able to inject it in the constructor, i was wondering if its possible to inject it as a property. This will bring me to my next question can i inject this in a plain model. I am using `class-transformer` to map http results to usable objects. I can create a locale.ts file that i can map to different builds and such so i have a usable work around but i would like to do this the most correct way

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {  

  @Inject(LOCALE_ID) public localeProperty: string;

  constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) public locale: string, public appService: AppService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    console.log('AppComponent.locale: ', this.locale);
    console.log('AppComponent.localeProperty: ', this.localeProperty);
```

> AppComponent.locale:  fr
>
> AppComponent.localeProperty:  undefined

In my Location model i want the model to know what label to use, ideally i want to be able to inject the LOCALE_ID

```
import {locale} from '../../environments/locale';


export class Location {

  enLabel: string;
  frLabel: string;

  // can i do something here
  constructor() {
  }

  get label() {
    return this[`${locale}Label`] ? this[`${locale}Label`] : this.enLabel;
  }
```

**git here**
https://github.com/ricardosaracino/class-transformer